# Upgrade from Focal to Groovy did not complete

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 20.10, software-sources

I got a new PC pre-loaded with Ubuntu Focal Fossa. I changed the UI to Kubuntu and upgraded  to Groovy Gorilla from Software Updater (after an update it told me an upgrade was available and I just selected the Upgrade button), and it seemed to work well (PC behavior is good in general, software sources are Groovy), but then I realized that it still reports "Focal" in os-release, and keeps telling me an upgrade (Groovy) is available

I used sudo do-release-upgrade to complete the upgrade, and it tried to, but failed. After updating repository info, it shows this:

- Updating repository information
- Third party sources disabled  Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool or your package manager.
- To continue please press [ENTER]

Then after I press ENTER, it continues up to calculating the changes, and then:

- Calculating the changes
- Restoring original system state
- Aborting
- Reading package lists... Done
- Building dependency tree
- Reading state information... Done

I verified all the sources displayed in "Software and Updates" are selected and not disabled, but this did not help. I suspect some sources (Focal sources?) have disappeared but are needed for this upgrade.

On my previous computer, I had used Kubuntu since Gutsy Gibbon, never had a problem like that. Any idea? I know I could reinstall from scratch, but if I can avoid it ...

### Thanks.

Update 5/9/21:
There is one error in main.log:

2021-05-09 14:35:36,406 ERROR Installing/upgrading 'baloo-kf5' failed

I tried to install baloo-kf5, but it was already installed. So I uninstalled it and restarted the upgrade, but it just re-installed it, and I was in the same situation as before - after a reboot, it completed the installation with the same error.

The last lines in the log are:

```
2021-05-09 14:35:36,950 DEBUG Upgradable, but held- back:  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,950 DEBUG Remove:  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,950 DEBUG Install:  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,950 DEBUG Upgrade:  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,973 DEBUG apt btrfs snapshots supported: False  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,973 DEBUG cache aufs_rw_dir: /tmp/  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,974 DEBUG Free space on /: 175477112832  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,974 DEBUG Dir /usr mounted on /  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,974 DEBUG Dir /var mounted on /  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,974 DEBUG Dir /boot mounted on /  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,974 DEBUG Dir /var/cache/apt/archives mounted on /  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,974 DEBUG Dir /tmp mounted on /  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,974 DEBUG Dir /home mounted on /  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,974 DEBUG Dir /tmp mounted on /  
2021-05-09 14:35:36,974 DEBUG fs_free contains: '{'/': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>, '/usr': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>, '/var': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>, '/boot': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>, '/var/cache/apt/archives': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>, '/tmp': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>, '/home': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>}'  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,242 DEBUG dir '/var/cache/apt/archives' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>' (175477112832.000000)  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,242 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>' (175477112832.000000)  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,242 DEBUG dir '/var' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>' (175477112832.000000)  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,242 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '52428800' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>' (175477112832.000000)  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,242 DEBUG dir '/boot' needs '85309190.4' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>' (175424684032.000000)  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,242 DEBUG dir '/tmp' needs '5242880' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>' (175339374841.600006)  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,242 DEBUG dir '/' needs '10485760' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>' (175334131961.600006)  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,242 DEBUG dir '/tmp' needs '0.0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>' (175323646201.600006)  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,242 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '0.0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7feb66a411f0>' (175323646201.600006)  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,242 DEBUG Found writable ESP /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,244 DEBUG demoted: 'libmpdec2'  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,244 DEBUG found components: {'groovy': {'universe', 'restricted', 'multiverse', 'main'}, 'groovy-updates': {'universe', 'restricted', 'multiverse', 'main'}, 'groovy-security': {'universe', 'restricted', 'multiverse', 'main'}}  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,244 DEBUG abort called  
2021-05-09 14:35:37,245 DEBUG openCache()  
2021-05-09 14:35:38,564 DEBUG Comparing 5.8.0-50 with  
2021-05-09 14:35:38,624 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 67707
```

I do not understand what caused the "abort called".

Comment: Guiverc, thanks for answering. I edited the post to address your question.

Comment: The question is unanswerable as currently written. The specific problem you are having is likely logged in /var/log/apt or /var/log/dist-upgrade. Do a bit of digging and reading to find out what really happened. If you don't understand what the log is telling you, add the specific entries that you need interpreted to your question above. Understanding the problem will lead to a solution.