# Upgrade from 19.10

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, update-manager, software-sources

I have a system that's currently on 19.10 and I would like to get it upgraded.  I didn't realize this wasn't on an LTS, so now I'm having trouble.

I've been through all the steps I can find including the EOL tutorials.  I have two problems.

The first has to do with /etc/apt/sources.list file.  The URLs have been changed from archive to old-releases and that seems to be OK, but if I run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop
```

I get these messages

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports Release                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
```

I cannot figure out where the "us.archive.ubuntu.com" is coming from.  Is there someplace besides the sources.list that the source urls are?

Then I went to the upgrade tools for specific releases (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release) and pulled down the focal update tool from here (UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/focal.tar.gz)

When I extract and run this it comes up with a box that lists the steps.  When it gets to the *Calculating the changes* step, it just resets and exits.

Is there a way to get a log to see why that focal script is failing?

Finally any other suggestions would be helpful.   There's a lot of configuration on this machine and I would prefer not to just to a clean install on it if I don't have to.

Edit: This question was marked as closed because it matched an other old question.  The answer to that question was to update `/etc/apt/sources.list` to reference `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com`.

I did this.

Here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
```

I see no references to `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` but I am getting an error related to that.

Comment: If you're running 19.10 or *eoan*, why is there a *jammy* (22.04) line in your paste?  That implies (*to me anyway*) a badly mangled system where I'd re-install.  You also didn't say if this is a desktop or server system (it matters on re-install options!).  LTS release are the first release on an *even* year, ie. 6.06, 8.04, 10.04, 12.04, 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, 20.04 & 22.04 - so why would 19.10 be one?  (*full development starts on the .10 release post-LTS from prior cycle; with 3 non-LTS release before cycle ends with a LTS release*)

Comment: Did you run `apt update` after editing /etc/apt ? Usually there also is a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder that could as well contain additional settings. From your description, I'd guess you did not edit all locations in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. From my experience, you will not need to re-setup the machine. Just make sure you replace all `us.archive` hostnames and run `apt update` afterwards (and, of course, `apt upgrade` before you attempt to `do-release-upgrade`).

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu Desktop system can be re-installed, without impacting user files and having *manually installed* packages auto-reinstalled.. I use this on boxes I keep for *support* purposes on systems where *dailies* are still produced, by performing a QA-test (*Quality Assurance*) install ~weekly which (a) updates packages at the same time as the QA-test. I also use it to *upgrade via re-install* an EOL release; eg. when my *impish* (21.10) system was EOL, I performed the re-install with *kinetic* (I already had a *jammy* system) that left my music etc untouched & apps got re-installed

Comment: An *upgrade via re-install* (Lubuntu refer to it as *install using existing partition* in the QA checklists) is what I'd use... but your provided details contain numerous *flaws*, let alone complications can exist if using 3rd party apps (*the install method is supported/intended for only Ubuntu repository software*) so a *clean* install maybe worthwhile, esp. given *eoan* was so long ago (two cycles ago).  The *upgrade via re-install* allows you to *skip* releases, but where data is important to you, check for package changes (*in those apps*) before using it...

Comment: You looked in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/` I assume.. but I didn't get a response for the *jammy* in my first comment; which would likely cause *breakage* on *release-upgrade* of your system anyway... thus I'd recommend re-install... You could try `ubuntu-security-status` & like tools but I suspect you're using a *frakensystem* (*thus results maybe inaccurate given your pasted details*)

Comment: It was fine as an eoan system until I started trying to upgrade it.

Just a personal desktop.  I didn't realize it was that far behind in updates and want to get it up to date.  It runs fine as is, for what I use it for, but I do have some custom configuration, Plex server, photo archives, etc.. sync with my phone, etc.. that I would need to dig through and figure out my setup if I can't have to reinstall.

_jammy_ (22.04) is in there because that's the lastest version so when I run `sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop` that's the version that tries to install.

Comment: As to why this was a 19.10 release?  I honestly don't remember.  It's a kubuntu install, it came up for an upgrade so I upgraded it.    In the future I will definitely try to stick to the LTS version.

Comment: And yes, i did run `apt update` and `apt upgrade` after every edit to the `/etc/apt/sources.list`

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` does not contain any references to `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` either

Comment: `/var/log/dist-upgrade/` is what I was looking for.  Thank you for that.

I tried to run the update just to focal so I could be back on an LTS, but it fails.  Looking through the main.log the only error I see is 
`ERROR Installing/upgrading 'baloo-kf5' failed`

That's referenced in this question which wasn't ever answered
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335643/upgrade-from-focal-to-groovy-did-not-complete